# Appinventor: How to set button/label visible after certain date has passed

Tags: date, datetime, app-inventor

I tried to add some function to an app i am creating and started a new project for it.

I want to display or hide a button after a certain (set) date has passed.
But I cannot get it to work.

(I am also not a programmer, I search the web, watch youtube and just try to play/edit with blocks to get it to work, but i am stuck now)

[Appinventor Blocks Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ka27.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

see also the documentation of the clock component and its methods here http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/sensors.html#Clock

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and useful reply. Also with the shared links.
I'll continue to play and edit with blocks and read tutorails and video's so I learn on the go.